# AppCode is not detecting errors before compiling

Tags: ios, swift, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I would like to know why AppCode is not highlighting errors/warning messages (nor swiftLint errors) directly in source editor; only after running the app errors/warnings are shown in Messages panel.

[image]

vs

[image]

I am using Version 2017.2.3 of AppCode.

Comment: [Have you seen this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249535/how-to-immediately-see-swift-errors-in-appcode) Which version of AppCode are you using?

Comment: Version 2017.2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked AppCode help center directly and this answer worked. Hope it helps someone too.

> Try building the target against device (instead of simulator) and reopen .swift file: in-editor warnings should work after that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it doesn't work for me in AC 2021.2.2. Here's my version infos:

> AppCode 2021.2.2 Build #OC-212.5284.45, built on September 14, 2021
> Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28 aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
> VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 11.4 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old
> Generation Memory: 4096M Cores: 8 Registry:
> max.suggested.heap.size=8192 Non-Bundled Plugins:
> com.intellij.plugin.applescript (0.121), com.appcodeplugins.swiftlint
> (1.13.4)

Edit: it seems to be [a known and very recent issue with XCode 13](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-22131).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30017481)